# AngularJS execute controller function in directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I made a custom directive with AngularJS,
and in the template I called a function in controller,
but it didn't work.

thanks for your help :)

```
<div ng-contorller="myCtrl">
    <ng-selectbox my-function="myfunction()" items="codes"></ng-selectbox>
</div>

myapp.controller("myCtrl", function($scpoe){
  $scope.myfunction= function(){
    alert("123");
  };
});

myapp.directive("ngSelectbox", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      items: "=",
      myfunction: "&"
    },
    template:
    "<div id='selectbox'>" +
    "<ul ng-repeat='item in items'>" +
    "<li ng-click='myfunction()'>{{item.TYPE}}</li>" +
    "</ul>" +
    "</div>"
  };
});
```

Comment: where is your controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not add calling brackets where you are using your directive , just use like this `<ng-selectbox my-function="myfunction" items="codes"></ng-selectbox>`

Comment: thank you, tried but didn't work :(
and what if I want to pass parameter through myfunction?

Comment: Hey, got the solution, you have used `my-function` attribute, and in directive  myfunction instead of myFunction , just replace `myfunction` with `myFunction` and it will work, see working example plnkr.co/edit/1CblTUHoMTZMKLOf4INE?p=preview

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! It really had confused me for a long time... thank you for solving it.

Comment: btw, do you have any idea about how to pass the clicked item through the function? I can only pass the whole array of items.

Comment: Yes sure, check working example(check console) : http://plnkr.co/edit/1CblTUHoMTZMKLOf4INE?p=preview

Comment: Just modify function scope to '='(two way binding).

Comment: Thank you Anand, I would like to say as many thank you as I can to you. Thank you so much for answering my question so precisely.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You should place your directive inside your controller wrapper like below.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <ng-selectbox my-function="myfunction()" items="codes"></ng-selectbox>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is inside my controller, sorry I didn't mention that.